# On the proof that every ordinal is either the initial ordinal, a successor ordinal or a limit ordinal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I was reading this paper http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/14.pdf (p. 206, or p. 8 on a pdf) on Naive Set Theory on the proof that every ordinal is either the initial ordinal (empty set), a successor ordinal or a limit ordinal.

The proof in the test made sense except for one line that I did not understand the reasoning behind:

"The assumption $\beta < \alpha$ gives $\beta \cup \{\beta\} \le \alpha$."

An explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Compare to natural numbers : β∪{β} is like $n+1$; thus, if $n < k$, then $n+1 \le k$.

Comment: isn't the initial ordinal also a limit ordinal? So, more simply, every ordinal is (exclusively) either a successor or a limit ordinal.

Comment: @Ittay: It's sometimes useful to separate the zero case.

Answer (score 7):

Recall that $\beta+1=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$. Therefore $\beta\cup\{\beta\}$ is the successor ordinal of $\beta$.

Being a successor means that whenever $\beta<\alpha$ we have that $\beta+1\leq\alpha$. And so this holds.